# importing opencv in python script called from Qt crashes

Tags: python, c++, qt, opencv

I'm embedding Python in Qt C++. When I import cv2 in the Python script it crashes with segmentation fault. Running the script in Python works. Running from C++ without Qt works.

Python scrip: works

```
print("Importing cv2")
import cv2
print("cv2 imported")
```

C++: works

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string module_name("PythonModule");

    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject* sysPath = PySys_GetObject((char*)"path");
    PyObject* pModuleDirPath = PyUnicode_FromString(".");
    PyList_Append(sysPath, pModuleDirPath);
    Py_DECREF(pModuleDirPath);

    PyObject* pModuleName = PyUnicode_FromString(module_name.c_str());
    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_Import(pModuleName);

    Py_DECREF(pModuleName);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Qt: segmentation fault after printing "Importing cv2"

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :         
    QMainWindow(parent),     
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)     
{         
    ui->setupUi(this);              

    std::string module_name("PythonModule");              
    Py_Initialize();              

    PyObject* sysPath = PySys_GetObject((char*)"path");         
    PyObject* pModuleDirPath = PyUnicode_FromString(".");     

    PyList_Append(sysPath, pModuleDirPath);         
    Py_DECREF(pModuleDirPath);              

    PyObject* pModuleName = PyUnicode_FromString(module_name.c_str());        
    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_Import(pModuleName);           

    Py_DECREF(pModuleName);         
    Py_DECREF(pModule);              

    Py_Finalize();     
}
```

.pro file:

```
LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib/python3.5m -lpython3.5m          
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/python3.5m
```

Versions:
Ubuntu 16.04
Python 3.5
opencv-python 3.4.2.17
Qt Creator 4.7.0 Based on Qt 5.11.1

Do anyone recognize this problem?

Comment: What is the path of the .py file?

Comment: When you point as the "." you are indicating that the .py is next to the executable, in the case of Qt Creator the executable is in the build folder, so I recommend using the complete path or copying the .py file to the build folder.

Comment: it is in the build folder. Note that in all cases the python script runs. But when using Qt it prints "Importing cv2" and crashes on the Import cv2 line.

Comment: okay, if so, then it seems weird, I've tried it and it works correctly

Comment: use the debugger to know in which line the program is broken

Comment: Thanks for trying it out! Debug in Qt stops at an assembly instruction "lock incl" during the PyImport_Import call. I have not been able to get any better information from debugging. Do you have a suggestions how to do it better?

Comment: @eyllanesc, I updated the question with what versions I'm using. Can you share yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that opencv uses Qt as well so a collision occurred.
The solution was to install opencv without Qt support:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python-headless/